# jQuery autocomplete not firing action when element is inside knockout "with" binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, autocomplete

I am trying to implement Autocomplete using jquery UI however the auto complete text box is inside the "with" knockout binding and so the MVC action is never getting fired.

```
<div data-bind="with: activeButton">
 //Some other div's...
  <div>
   <input type="text" id="autoCompleteText" data-autocomplete-url="@Url.Action("Autocomplete")"/>
  </div>
</div>

//On DOM ready
$('*[data-autocomplete-url]').each(function () {
      $(this).autocomplete({
          source: $(this).data("autocomplete-url")
      });
  });
```

Do I have to do something different to fire the MVC action when the autocomplete element is inside "with" knockout binding?

Comment: Do you realise there is a space in "data-autocomplete- url"? If this is in your code then it could be breaking it.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: That was not in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need knockout binding handler for jquery ui autocomplete. Something like

```
<div data-bind="with: activeButton">
//Some other div's...
      <input type="text" id="autoCompleteText" data-bind='textInput: someSelectedValue, autoComplete:{source: "@Url.Action("Autocomplete")" }' />
</div>
```

Knockout binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var autoCompleteOptions = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); // Get the current value of the current property we're bound to
        $(element).autocomplete(autoCompleteOptions); 
    }
};
```